# Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{k(1+\alpha)}{n-k+1+(n-k)\alpha}\right)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, physics

Does the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{k(1+\alpha)}{n-k+1+(n-k)\alpha}\right)$$
exist?

Background: I came across this limit when considering the rocket equation for a rocket with $n$ stages. Each stage has a dry mass $m_d$ and fuel mass $m_f$ and $\alpha\equiv m_f/m_d$. The limit calculates how much $\Delta v$ one gets given some $\alpha$. I was wondering if there's a limit to how much $\Delta v$ one can get out of a rocket by letting the number of stages go to infinity. For more background see [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/56134/42334).

Comment: Assuming we're working in real numbers, your logarithm is not even defined for large $n$. Take a look at the [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tlubyy6lcm). That'd make the limit undefined as well.

Comment: @bjorn93 Are you sure that matters? You plotted for $k$ and $k$ is never larger than $m$. For $k\leq m$ it appears to be defined which you can see if you plot $x=m$.

Comment: Since you have a sum from $k=1$ to $n$ and a limit as $n\to\infty$, the logarithm needs to be defined for an arbitrarily large $k$. The plot shows this isn't the case. The logarithm is only defined for $k\le N$ where $N$ is some number.

Comment: Did you mean $n$ in the sum instead of $m$? Cause otherwise this question doesn't make sense

Comment: @QC_QAOA Oops I messed them up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $1+\alpha=\beta^{-1}$. We can rewrite the term within the logarithm as

$$
f(n,k,\beta)=\frac{k}{n-k+\beta}
$$

We can find the finite sum

$$
S_n(\beta)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \ln f(n,k,\beta)=\ln\left[\prod\limits_{k=1}^n f(n,k,\beta)  \right]
$$

Write out a few terms of the product

$$
\prod\limits_{k=1}^n f(n,k,\beta)=\frac{1}{n+\beta-1}\cdot
\frac{2}{n+\beta-2}\cdots \frac{n}{\beta}
$$

Which may be written as

$$
\prod\limits_{k=1}^n f(n,k,\beta)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+\beta)/\Gamma(\beta)}
$$

So we have for the sum

$$
S_n(\beta)=\ln\left[\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(n+\beta)} \right]
$$

Using the asymptotic expansion of $\Gamma$ for large argument with fixed $\beta$

$$
S_n(\beta)\sim (1-\beta)\ln n \qquad , \qquad n\to \infty
$$

So that the sum in logarithmically divergent unless $\beta=1$, in which case $S_n(1)=\ln\Gamma(1)=0$

Comment: Very nice! I think that $\beta^{-1}=1+\alpha$ is a very clever substitution. I have to think about the implications but it seems to imply that a rocket with inifinite stages could reach arbitrary velocities. Also it's nice that $beta=1$ corresponds to $\alpha=0$ meaning having zero fuel is the only exception because it gives you zero velocity.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Thank you! Taking the $n \to \infty$ limit means each stage has vanishing total mass; which, even abstractly, is difficult to imagine is feasible. I imagine there is something like an absolute minimal mass per stage. On the other hand, this 'continuum limit' corresponds to a rocket that is losing mass both to fuel *and* something else